# Meteor router /undefined route?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

When I load any page in my meteor app, I see the following error in the dev console:

```
  (index):1 Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type 
    text/html: "http://localhost:3000/undefined".
```

so all of my routes initially load as "undefined", even the index "/" route which isn't passed any parameters. This doesn't seem to be causing anything to break, but I would like to figure out why it's happening and maybe how to prevent it.

Comment: can you please put more code here?  routes.js will be great

Comment: If you see "undefined" anywhere it's usually because you are trying to use an undeclared/uninitialized variable somewhere

Comment: @Ethaan even if I trim my router file down to this:  `Router.route '/', ->  @render('main') `
I still see the same error

Comment: @Suppen understood but how would the undefined variable make its way into the url?

Comment: @gaplus can i see all the html inside the `main` template?

Comment: Yep, we need to see code.